# Flutter parse unicode characters not working

Tags: android, ios, flutter, character-encoding, flutter-web

I have the following string coming from my backend server `\u25CF\u25CF\u25CF` and when I decode it with UTF-8 it's working fine in the iOS native app, But when I try to parse it in flutter I'm not able to get the converted value. I have tried the following approaches but none worked

```
String converted = Utf8Decoder().convert(userName.codeUnits);
String uname = utf8.decode(userName.runes.toList());
String runes = String.fromCharCodes(Runes('$userName'));
```

Does anyone know how we can fix this? The real value should be 3 dots after conversion.

**Update**

This is json parsing code

```
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        Map<String, dynamic> postResponse = response.data;
        var postsJson = postResponse["posts"];
     
        for (var postObjet in postsJson) {
          Map<String, dynamic> finalMap = Map<String, dynamic>.from(postObjet);
          Post p = Post.fromMap(finalMap);
          posts.add(p);
          
        }
}
```

Sample JSON Response

```
The Chat service we\u2019ve been paying for since our launch
```

Comment: That's not JSON. A JSON string must be surrounded by double quotes, and is typically wrapped in an object or list.

Comment: Yes, it was surrounded by quotes. It was in an object. I have printed the variable using debug print command after parsing the model.

Comment: can we connect over Skype or some other tool where I can share my screen and show you the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are starting with a string with unicode escapes and you want to end up with a string containing the actual unicode characters. This is easy if the input contains only unicode escapes as you can simply strip out the `\u` and parse the hex to a code point.

```
  final input = '\\u25CF\\u25CF\\u25CF'; // note I have to double the \ as this is source code
  var hexPoints = input.split('\\u').sublist(1);
  print(hexPoints); // [25CF, 25CF, 25CF]

  // convert to a string from codepoints, parsing each hex string to an int
  final result = String.fromCharCodes(
    hexPoints.map<int>((e) => int.parse(e, radix: 16)).toList(),
  );
  print(result); // dot, dot, dot
```

The more general solution where there may be a mixture of escaped and unescaped characters is to use a regular expression that matches \xnnnn, parses the nnnn as hex and replaces it with that code point.

```
String sanitize(String s) => s.replaceAllMapped(
      RegExp(r'\\u([0-9a-fA-F]{4})'),
      (Match m) => String.fromCharCode(int.parse(m.group(1)!, radix: 16)),
    );
```

Use it like this:

```
print(sanitize('ab\\u25CF\\u25CF\\u25CFcd')); //ab<dot><dot><dot>cd
```

Finally, note that if these escaped strings are appearing inside JSON, the JSON decoder will automatically convert them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you also update the code so that if Unicode escapes come in the middle of the string then also how we can extract and parse it? My final goal is to show @taggedUsers with a hyperlink color and I should be able to click on that. Also the string could have hyperlinks, emojis, tagged users, etc. All into a single string so how I can do that? Can you help me in this direction?

Comment: Also, I tried your code and it shows square boxes with X inside them on the web platform. WIll it work fine in the production release?

Comment: It's already coming in JSON response but the decoder is not converting it automatically. All I see is \u25cf on the text widget in flutter web and mobile. Also, does code point will always be of 4 characters?

Comment: JSON response string doesn't have double \\ I guess

Comment: I just re-tested the JSON decoder and it does successfully decode `\uxxxx` escapes. Note that the json should include just a single backslash - there are two in the snippet above because it's source code.

Comment: My JSON response has a single backslash before every unicode but it didn't work. I can share JSON response.

Comment: I'm adding JSON and JSON parsing code in original question

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [characters](https://pub.dev/packages/characters) package instead of runes. Seems like it can solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks will check it out. Any code snippet you can provide for my use case?

Comment: Tried this but no luck String nameConverted = Characters(userName).toString();