# Decode Unicode when it's a sum of Strings

Tags: string, flutter, unicode, sum

I have a Unicode String as a sum of 6 substrings:

```
String unicode = '\\' + 'u' + '0' + '0' + 'e' + '4';
```

So is there any chance in flutter to decode it into a unicode String like that:

```
String unicodeString = '\u00e4';
```

Thanks a lot for your helping!

Comment: See how to do it in general with a regular expression here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72910174/flutter-parse-unicode-characters-not-working/72913146#72913146

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this can be easily done:

- extract the hexadecimal number after `\u`
- convert it to an integer, resulting in a Unicode codepoint
- convert the codepoint to a string

```
String unicode = '\\u00e4';
var codepoint = int.parse(unicode.substring(2, 6), radix: 16);
String unicodeString = String.fromCharCode(codepoint);
print(unicodeString);
```

Also note that you can just write `'\\u00e4'`. As it starts with a double backslash, this is indeed a string with 6 characters (and not equal to `'\u00e4'`).